# How to get value from api url?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

The below data is returned as `json` value. Please help me how to **get the value or data** in `jquery ajax`.

```
{"detail":
    {    "ID":001,
        "Email":"test@test.com",
        "Tel":"123-456-789",
        "FirstName":"John",
        "MiddleName":null,
        "LastName":"Abraham",
        "Prefix":null,
        "Suffix":null,
        "Street":"123 Mew Street",
        "City":"New York",
        "Region":"NY",
        "Country":"USA",
        "PostCode":"1011",
        "Latitude":null,
        "Longitude":null,
        "valid":1,
        "message":"success"
        }
```

I have tried like below coding please advise me to update the code.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET", 
      url: url,
      dataType : 'json',
      async: false,  
      success : function(text)  { response = text; } 
});
alert(response);
```

Comment: Don't use `async: false`. Is this a cross domain ajax call?

Comment: yes Johan.. This is cross domain

Comment: try http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: @user1944788 - doesn't matter if it's cross domain, you still shouldn't be using synchronous ajax, which stands for **Asynchronous Javascript And XML**

Comment: You can't make a cross domain call unless the datatype is jsonp, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

To access ID, you can use below code:

```
response.detail.ID
```

Similarly, access other fields

Answer (score 0):

You can access JSON data by referencing the keys. For e.g.

```
 success : function(text) {
    response = text;  
    var id = response.detail.ID;
    var email = response.detail.Email;
    // AND Other properties........
 }
```

Comment: The above answered is not working for me. Please guide me from $.ajax code.

Comment: Try using _JSONP_. Have a look at **[THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)**.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
   $.getJSON( url, function( response ) {
       response.detail.ID  //001
    });
```